# How to create a Non-Transparent control container

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to roll my own Expander object.  For this object, I need to create a control container that when it is visible, everything underneath it is hidden just to the bounds of the container.

Of course I also need to place controls in the control container, such as Labels, TextBox, etc.

Is there a way to handle this.  Even when I make the Opaque property 100%, everything below my current object shows through.  I've tried Canvas, Grid, etc, and nothing seems to use the Opaque property. I even tried using the Expander object, but it's just as transparent as everything else. I must be missing something.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can take two Grid controls inside a single Grid control

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="grid1" Height="200" Width="200" Background="Yellow">
            <Label Content="Hello Grid1"/>
            <TextBox Text="Hi Grid1" Height="20" Width="50"/>

        </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="grid2" Height="200" Width="200" Background="Red" Visibility="Visible">
            <Label Content="Hello Grid2"/>
            <TextBox Text="Hi Grid2" Height="20" Width="50"/>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Visibility of the second Grid "grid2" can be changed according to the requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, when I place that in a user control that then sits on top of a window, the contents of the window still show through. Is there something about the interaction between a WPF window and a User Control?

Comment: You should add the code in your Window.xaml and not Usercontrol.xaml\n<Grid>
        <Grid Background="Red">
            <TextBox Text="Hi I am a window" Height="50" Background="Aqua" />
        </Grid>
        
        <Grid>
            <uc:UserControl1 Height="200" Width="200" Visibility="Visible"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

Comment: Place that Grid control in <Window> Tag

Answer (score 0):

For reference for others. What I ended up doing was to create a completely separate window for the expander window and set it's WindowStyle to "None", BorderThickness to 0, ResizeMode to "NoResize and ShowInTaskbar = false.

When displaying, I instantiated this window and placed it's position relative to where I wanted it to display according to the window below.  This works perfectly with the exception that I can't move the window underneath while the window on top is displayed. This may also be handled by doing a Show instead of a ShowDialog and then moving the top window as I move the window underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate exactly what you want to do?

the description you've given here shows, according what i'm catching up, that you want to display components properly within the Expander control. Nothing more...

Please Try to elaborate the problem wiht some example code.